# std::variant, a wrapper class, and 'conversion from ... to non-scalar type ... requested'

Tags: c++, c++17, variant

I have mutually recursive variant types: Value, Array, and Object. The crux of the matter is that I can assign one of the variant types to a Value when it is nested within an Array or Object, which can both contain Value. I cannot assign directly to a Value. The `main()` function code at the bottom should make this clear. The compiler (GNU GCC 7.2) gives me errors like:

```
error: conversion from 'JSON::Integer {aka long unsigned int}' to non-scalar type 'JSON::Value' requested
  Value v = Integer( 7 );
```

and oddly does not provide any additional information about assignment operator candidates or anything else. Further, it isn't clear to me how assignment operators I have defined in Value are affecting this problem. Complete working example code follows. Any assignment of one of the variant types directly to a Value type in `main()` causes a compiler error just like the one above for the `Integer` type.

Thanks in advance!

### Object Class

```
#ifndef JSON_OBJECT_HPP
#define JSON_OBJECT_HPP

#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include "Value.hpp"

namespace JSON {
    class Object {
        public:
            using Key = std::string;

        private:
            using values_t = std::unordered_map<Key,Value>;
            values_t values;

        public:
            Object() = default;

            Value & operator[]( Key const & key ) {
                auto it = values.emplace( key, Value() );
                return it.first->second;
            }

            Value const & operator[]( Key const & key ) const {
                auto it = values.find( key );
                return it->second;
            }
            bool has_key( Key const & key ) const {
                auto it = values.find( key );
                return it != values.end();
            }
            bool operator==( Object const & rhs ) const {
                return values == rhs.values;
            }
            values_t::const_iterator begin() const {
                return values.begin();
            }
            values_t::const_iterator end( ) const {
                return values.end();
            }
            values_t::iterator begin() {
                return values.begin();
            }
            values_t::iterator end() {
                return values.end();
            }
    };

    bool operator==( Object const & lhs, Object const & rhs ) {
        return lhs.operator==( rhs );
    }

    std::ostream & operator<<( std::ostream & os, Object const & object ) {
        os << '{';
        auto begin = object.begin();
        auto end = object.end();
        if( begin != end ) {
            os << std::quoted( begin->first ) << ':' << begin->second;
        }
        while( ++begin != end ) {
            os << ',' << std::quoted( begin->first ) << ':' << begin->second;
        }
        os << '}';
    }
}

#endif
```

### Array Class

```
#ifndef JSON_ARRAY_HPP
#define JSON_ARRAY_HPP

#include <vector>
#include "types.hpp"
#include "Value.hpp"

namespace JSON {
    std::ostream & operator<<( std::ostream &, Value & );

    class Array {
        private:
            using values_t = std::vector<Value>;
            values_t values;
        public:
            using Key = values_t::size_type;
            Array() = default;
            Value & operator[]( Key key ) {
                if( !has_key( key ) ) {
                    values.resize( key + 1 );
                }
                return values[key];
            }
            Value const & operator[]( Key key ) const {
                return values[key];
            }
            bool has_key( Key key ) const {
                return key < values.size();
            }
            bool operator==( Array const & rhs ) const {
                return values == rhs.values;
            }
            values_t::const_iterator begin() const {
                return values.begin();
            }
            values_t::const_iterator end( ) const {
                return values.end();
            }
            values_t::iterator begin() {
                return values.begin();
            }
            values_t::iterator end() {
                return values.end();
            }
    };

    bool operator==( Array const & lhs, Array const & rhs ) {
        return lhs.operator==( rhs );
    }

    std::ostream & operator<<( std::ostream & os, Array const & array ) {
        os << '[';
        auto begin = array.begin();
        auto end = array.end();
        if( begin != end ) {
            os << *begin;
        }
        while( ++begin != end ) {
            os << ',' << *begin;
        }
        os << ']';
    }
}

#endif
```

### Value Class

```
#ifndef JSON_VALUE_HPP
#define JSON_VALUE_HPP

#include <iomanip>
#include <type_traits>
#include <variant>
#include <boost/variant/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/variant/recursive_wrapper.hpp>
#include "types.hpp"

namespace JSON {
    class Object;
    class Array;
    bool operator==( Object const & lhs, Object const & rhs );
    bool operator==( Array const & lhs, Array const & rhs );
    std::ostream & operator<<( std::ostream &, Object const & object );
    std::ostream & operator<<( std::ostream &, Array const & array );
    template<class T> struct always_false : std::false_type {};

    class Value {
        private:
            using variant_t = std::variant<Undefined,String,Integer,Number,boost::recursive_wrapper<Object>,boost::recursive_wrapper<Array> >;
            variant_t data;
            friend std::ostream & operator<<( std::ostream & os, Value const & value );
        public:
            Value() = default;
            bool operator==( Value const & rhs ) const {
                return std::visit(
                        []( auto && lhs, auto && rhs ) -> bool {
                            using lhsT = std::decay_t<decltype( lhs )>;
                            using rhsT = std::decay_t<decltype( rhs )>;
                            if constexpr ( std::is_same_v< lhsT, rhsT> ) {
                                if constexpr (std::is_same_v< lhsT, boost::recursive_wrapper<Object> > ) {
                                    return lhs.get() == rhs.get();
                                } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v< lhsT, boost::recursive_wrapper<Array> > ) {
                                        return lhs.get() == rhs.get();
                                } else {
                                    return lhs == rhs;
                                }
                            } else {
                                return false;
                            }
                        },
                        data,
                        rhs.data
                        );
            }
            Value & operator=( String const & rhs ) {
                data = rhs;
                return *this;
            }
            Value & operator=( Integer const & rhs ) {
                data = rhs;
                return *this;
            }
            Value & operator=( Object const & rhs ) {
                data = rhs;
                return *this;
            }
            Value & operator=( Array const & rhs ) {
                data = rhs;
                return *this;
            }

    };

    std::ostream & operator<<( std::ostream & os, Value const & value ) {
        std::visit(
                [&os]( auto && arg ) {
                    using T = std::decay_t<decltype( arg )>;
                    if constexpr ( std::is_same_v< T, Undefined > ) {
                        os << "undefined";
                    } else if constexpr ( std::is_same_v< T, String > ) {
                        os << std::quoted( arg );
                    } else if constexpr ( std::is_same_v< T, Integer > ) {
                        os << arg;
                    } else if constexpr ( std::is_same_v< T, Number > ) {
                        os << arg;
                    } else if constexpr ( std::is_same_v< T, boost::recursive_wrapper<Object> > ) {
                        os << arg.get();
                    } else if constexpr ( std::is_same_v< T, boost::recursive_wrapper<Array> > ) {
                        os << arg.get();
                    } else if constexpr ( std::is_same_v< T, Boolean > ) {
                        os << (arg == false ? "false" : "true");
                    } else if constexpr ( std::is_same_v< T, Null > ) {
                        os << "null";
                    } else {
                        static_assert( always_false<T>::value, "non-exhaustive visitor" );
                    }
                },
                value.data
                );
    }
}

#endif
```

### Type Definitions

```
#ifndef TYPES_HPP
#define TYPES_HPP

namespace JSON {
    template <typename Tag> struct Literal {
        bool operator==( Literal const & ) const {
            return true;
        }
        bool operator<( Literal const & ) const {
            return false;
        }
    };
    using String = std::string;
    using Integer = uint64_t;
    using Number = double;
    class Object;
    class Array;
    using Boolean = bool;
    using Null = Literal<struct tag_null>;
    using Undefined = Literal<struct tag_undefined>;
}

#endif
```

### Main Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Array.hpp"
#include "Object.hpp"
#include "Value.hpp"

using namespace JSON;

int main() {
    Object o;
    o["fun"] = "what?"; // compiles fin
    o["stuff"] = "yeah!"; // compiles fine
    o["inttest"] = Integer( 44 ); // compiles fine
    Array a;
    a[2] = "yo"; // compiles fine
    a[3] = Integer( 6 ); // compiles fine
    o["arrtest"] = a;
//  Value v = a; // fails to compile
    Value v = Integer( 7 ); // fails to compile
    std::cout << v;
    std::cout << o << "\n";
    std::cout << a << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, `JSON::Value` indeed doesn't offer any constructor that would take a `JSON::Integer`. What exactly did you expect `Value v = Integer( 7 );` to do? It's an initialization, not an assignment (in case you hoped `operator=` would be used).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Well...that's embarrassing. You hit the nail on the head, of course.

Comment: This is **A LOT** of code. Please provide a [mcve], emphasis on minimal.

Comment: @Barry Sorry. That makes me sad. I will try to do better next time. The whole "mutually recursive bit" made me feel like removing any of the code could potentially affect the generality of a proposed answer, though obviously given the final solution that would not have been the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bad question with an embarrassing oversight. As the commenter pointed out, the problematic lines in `main()` were initializations rather than assignments. Providing the appropriate constructors solved the problem. For completeness, corrected code follows. It compiles and works fine under GNU GCC 7.2.

### Object Class

```
#ifndef JSON_OBJECT_HPP
#define JSON_OBJECT_HPP

#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include "Value.hpp"

namespace JSON {
    class Object {
        public:
            using Key = std::string;

        private:
            using values_t = std::unordered_map<Key,Value>;
            values_t values;

        public:
            Object() = default;

            Value & operator[]( Key const & key ) {
                auto it = values.emplace( key, Value() );
                return it.first->second;
            }

            Value const & operator[]( Key const & key ) const {
                auto it = values.find( key );
                return it->second;
            }
            bool has_key( Key const & key ) const {
                auto it = values.find( key );
                return it != values.end();
            }
            bool operator==( Object const & rhs ) const {
                return values == rhs.values;
            }
            values_t::const_iterator begin() const {
                return values.begin();
            }
            values_t::const_iterator end( ) const {
                return values.end();
            }
            values_t::iterator begin() {
                return values.begin();
            }
            values_t::iterator end() {
                return values.end();
            }
    };

    bool operator==( Object const & lhs, Object const & rhs ) {
        return lhs.operator==( rhs );
    }

    std::ostream & operator<<( std::ostream & os, Object const & object ) {
        os << '{';
        auto begin = object.begin();
        auto end = object.end();
        if( begin != end ) {
            os << std::quoted( begin->first ) << ':' << begin->second;
        }
        while( ++begin != end ) {
            os << ',' << std::quoted( begin->first ) << ':' << begin->second;
        }
        os << '}';
    }
}

#endif
```

### Array Class

```
#ifndef JSON_ARRAY_HPP
#define JSON_ARRAY_HPP

#include <vector>
#include "types.hpp"
#include "Value.hpp"

namespace JSON {
    std::ostream & operator<<( std::ostream &, Value const & );

    class Array {
        private:
            using values_t = std::vector<Value>;
            values_t values;
        public:
            using Key = values_t::size_type;
            Array() = default;
            Value & operator[]( Key key ) {
                if( !has_key( key ) ) {
                    values.resize( key + 1 );
                }
                return values[key];
            }
            Value const & operator[]( Key key ) const {
                return values[key];
            }
            bool has_key( Key key ) const {
                return key < values.size();
            }
            bool operator==( Array const & rhs ) const {
                return values == rhs.values;
            }
            values_t::const_iterator begin() const {
                return values.begin();
            }
            values_t::const_iterator end( ) const {
                return values.end();
            }
            values_t::iterator begin() {
                return values.begin();
            }
            values_t::iterator end() {
                return values.end();
            }
    };

    bool operator==( Array const & lhs, Array const & rhs ) {
        return lhs.operator==( rhs );
    }

    std::ostream & operator<<( std::ostream & os, Array const & array ) {
        os << '[';
        auto begin = array.begin();
        auto end = array.end();
        if( begin != end ) {
            os << *begin;
        }
        while( ++begin != end ) {
            os << ',' << *begin;
        }
        os << ']';
    }
}

#endif
```

### Value Class

```
#ifndef JSON_VALUE_HPP
#define JSON_VALUE_HPP

#include <iomanip>
#include <type_traits>
#include <variant>
#include <boost/variant/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/variant/recursive_wrapper.hpp>
#include "types.hpp"

namespace JSON {
    class Object;
    class Array;
    bool operator==( Object const & lhs, Object const & rhs );
    bool operator==( Array const & lhs, Array const & rhs );
    std::ostream & operator<<( std::ostream &, Object const & object );
    std::ostream & operator<<( std::ostream &, Array const & array );
    template<class T> struct always_false : std::false_type {};

    class Value {
        private:
            using variant_t = std::variant<Undefined,String,Integer,Number,boost::recursive_wrapper<Object>,boost::recursive_wrapper<Array> >;
            variant_t data;
            friend std::ostream & operator<<( std::ostream & os, Value const & value );
        public:
            Value() = default;
            template <typename T> Value( T const & rhs ) : data( rhs ) {}
            bool operator==( Value const & rhs ) const {
                return std::visit(
                        []( auto && lhs, auto && rhs ) -> bool {
                            using lhsT = std::decay_t<decltype( lhs )>;
                            using rhsT = std::decay_t<decltype( rhs )>;
                            if constexpr ( std::is_same_v< lhsT, rhsT> ) {
                                if constexpr (std::is_same_v< lhsT, boost::recursive_wrapper<Object> > ) {
                                    return lhs.get() == rhs.get();
                                } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v< lhsT, boost::recursive_wrapper<Array> > ) {
                                        return lhs.get() == rhs.get();
                                } else {
                                    return lhs == rhs;
                                }
                            } else {
                                return false;
                            }
                        },
                        data,
                        rhs.data
                        );
            }
    };

    std::ostream & operator<<( std::ostream & os, Value const & value ) {
        std::visit(
                [&os]( auto && arg ) {
                    using T = std::decay_t<decltype( arg )>;
                    if constexpr ( std::is_same_v< T, Undefined > ) {
                        os << "undefined";
                    } else if constexpr ( std::is_same_v< T, String > ) {
                        os << std::quoted( arg );
                    } else if constexpr ( std::is_same_v< T, Integer > ) {
                        os << arg;
                    } else if constexpr ( std::is_same_v< T, Number > ) {
                        os << arg;
                    } else if constexpr ( std::is_same_v< T, boost::recursive_wrapper<Object> > ) {
                        os << arg.get();
                    } else if constexpr ( std::is_same_v< T, boost::recursive_wrapper<Array> > ) {
                        os << arg.get();
                    } else if constexpr ( std::is_same_v< T, Boolean > ) {
                        os << (arg == false ? "false" : "true");
                    } else if constexpr ( std::is_same_v< T, Null > ) {
                        os << "null";
                    } else {
                        static_assert( always_false<T>::value, "non-exhaustive visitor" );
                    }
                },
                value.data
                );
    }
}

#endif
```

### Type Definitions

```
#ifndef JSON_TYPES_HPP
#define JSON_TYPES_HPP

namespace JSON {
    template <typename Tag> struct Literal {
        bool operator==( Literal const & ) const {
            return true;
        }
        bool operator<( Literal const & ) const {
            return false;
        }
    };
    using String = std::string;
    using Integer = uint64_t;
    using Number = double;
    class Object;
    class Array;
    using Boolean = bool;
    using Null = Literal<struct tag_null>;
    using Undefined = Literal<struct tag_undefined>;
}

#endif
```

### Main Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Array.hpp"
#include "Object.hpp"
#include "Value.hpp"

using namespace JSON;

int main() {
    Object o;
    o["fun"] = "what?";
    o["stuff"] = "yeah!";
    o["inttest"] = Integer( 44 );
    Array a;
    a[2] = "yo";
    a[3] = Integer( 6 );
    o["arrtest"] = a;
//  Value v = a;
    Value v = Integer( 7 );
    std::cout << v << "\n";
    std::cout << o << "\n";
    std::cout << a << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```